# ads interstitial not visible

Tags: android, admob

Hi guys i have a problem with my Ads interstitial. I have a banner in MainActivity but in another activity i want display an interstitial ADS. The banner is ok... i can see this! but interstitial doesn't show...
this is my code:

```
public class Servizi extends FragmentActivity{

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.servizi);       


     // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-....");

    // Create ad request.
//    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB")  // Emulator id you will get in the LogCat verbose
    .build();
    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    displayInterstitial();
  }

// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
public void displayInterstitial() {
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
  }
}
```

}

My UnitID is correct: there is a logcat.

```
    05-27 19:25:36.467: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2670): Google Play services is missing.
05-27 19:25:36.547: I/Ads(2670): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
05-27 19:25:36.567: I/Ads(2670): Starting ad request.
05-27 19:25:37.467: I/Choreographer(2670): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 19:25:38.927: I/Choreographer(2670): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 19:25:47.457: I/Ads(2670): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-27 19:25:47.457: I/Ads(2670): Ad finished loading.
05-27 19:25:48.077: I/Ads(2670): Ad finished loading.
05-27 19:26:47.497: I/Ads(2670): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
05-27 19:26:47.497: I/Ads(2670): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-27 19:27:47.537: I/Ads(2670): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
05-27 19:27:47.537: I/Ads(2670): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-27 19:28:47.617: I/Ads(2670): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

I use an emulator with 4.4.2 but i have tried on phisical device but doesn't work ads interstitial, but banner small in mainactivity work !

I have GooglePlayService lib... my app use google-map API and admob small banner... OThis is ok!
Thank you in advance!

** SOLVED **
I have implemented:

```
Solved: i have implemeted:

private class InterstitialAdListener extends AdListener {
    /** Called when an ad is loaded. */
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
          interstitial.show();

      Toast.makeText(Servizi.this, "onloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this incorrectly.

Do **not** call `interstital.show()` from `onAdLoaded`. It will give a very poor user experience.

You should instead call `interstitial.show()` from a natural break point in your app.

Also, the log indictaes that the ad is auto refresh every 60 secs. That should not happen for an interstitial ad. You need to explicitly load and show them. It means that you are using a banner AdUnitId instead of an interstitial adUnitId.

Create an Interstitial adUnitId and use that instead.